# How to get data from from different excel sheets and paste into one sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel, excel-2003

I'm having number of excel sheets. But in the sheet 1  I'm having the numbers for suppose 1 to 10. But no data is there in the sheet 1. I have to copy from the remaining sheets and get it in sheet1 from 1 to 10. How can I get values from all the remaining sheets with in the 1 to 10 .

like:

```
sheet 1:
1
2
3
4
5
sheet 2:
1  micheal  100000  dass125   car
2
3
4  jhon     20000   bad1245   jeep
5
sheet 3:
1
2  brad     20000   bcad1254  truck
3
4
5
```

how can I get all the data in sheet 2 and sheet 3 and get in sheet 1 from 1 to 5?

Comment: The syntax for links between sheets: =Sheetname!Cell
for example: if you work on sheet1 and A1 you want to copy A1 from sheet2 then the equation for A1 on Sheet1 = Sheet2!A1

Comment: Will Sheet2 and Sheet3 ever have duplicate rows? Or will one always be blank?

Comment: NO, as it is. sheet 2 and sheet 3 will be like that only,there will be  blank only

Comment: Please see my solution below .. It basically looks at Sheet2 first, and if it's blank, gets the value from Sheet3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better solution, but here's what I came up with:

In Sheet1!A1, put

```
=IF(Sheet2!A1<>"", Sheet2!A1, Sheet3!A1)
```

In Sheet1!B1, put

```
=IF(Sheet2!B1<>"", Sheet2!B1, Sheet3!B1)
```

In Sheet1!C1, put

```
=IF(Sheet2!C1<>"", Sheet2!C1, Sheet3!C1)
```

In Sheet1!D1, put

```
=IF(Sheet2!D1<>"", Sheet2!D1, Sheet3!D1)
```

Then copy this down to all 10 rows in Sheet1. This assumes your sheets have the data you listed in columns A thru D.

Comment: If each row has data on only one sheet you could just use `=Sheet2!A1 & Sheet3!A1`, fill right and down.